# Does energy in Spotify api featrue mean arousal?

Tags: theory, technique, practice, learning

I have a question about the spotify api feature.

The spotify api has valence and energy features. Is it correct that energy means the arousal of valence-arousal?

Thank you for your reply.

Comment: Welcome! There are some interesting [musicological ideas to ponder around this](https://web.archive.org/web/20170422195736/http://blog.echonest.com/post/66097438564/plotting-musics-emotional-valence-1950-2013), but I'm honestly not sure what's being asked. Please take a look [the topics covered here](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [how to avoid subjective answers](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask), then consider editing the question.